# Normal distribution in nature

Tags: probability, statistics, soft-question, normal-distribution

I applied for a job as a mathematician. In one of the test questions they asked the following: Why normal distribution is so common in nature?

What do you think?

Comment: If you add up many random quantities which are independent or nearly so, and which don't vary too much, the resulting distribution is approximately normal. This is the central limit theorem. Technically the CLT is actually a family of theorems with slightly different hypotheses, having to do with weakening the assumptions of "independent", "identically distributed", and "finite mean and variance". The Lindeberg CLT is the most well-known of these, and weakens the "identically distributed" hypothesis.

Comment: Maybe the right question is why is the normal distribution used so often by people to model phenomena, even when the fit is empirically not very good.

Comment: Related: http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/39082/2592